# visual studio emulator dont run app and xaml page in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android, visual-studio-emulator

I'm new in xamarin.
I've installed xamarin in visual studio 2015 and I spent all the steps mentioned in xamarin site and I created a sample project in visual studio for xamarin when I have running project visual studio emulator running up success but don't deploy app or xaml page.

This is my xaml page that I want to see after running emulator:

[image: click to see image()]

After running xaml, the page doesn't show:

[image: click to see image(after running xaml page dont show)]

In image2 emulator dont show xaml page

Comment: The image2 just launched the emulator do not deploy your project. Do not close your emulator and run your project again in the same emulator.

Comment: Yes I know,but after a hour emulator don't show page or app

Comment: Build your app again do not close your emulator, any messages shows up?

Comment: excuse me,I don't understand
You'll say I build solution when emulator is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android is set to Android SDK value you see in Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings. Then close everything, and try again.

Reference: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43538

Comment: Thanks for your comment
I have manul installed sdk and jdk and i have not this address in regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android

Comment: It seems the problem is that the VS Android emulator is using a different set of Android SDK tools than Xamarin. The VS Emulator uses a regkey somewhere to set the SDK location... maybe HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Android? Look around a bit

Comment: Do i have to install native visual studio android sdk?

Comment: Thanks that worked success for me
I have install android sdk for visual studio and then change this path in regedit  to my android sdk path !!!!